# Application of Removing Items from Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary that contains instances of kinematic objects. Each kinematic object has a position, velocity, etc. On each timestep update for the program, I want to check to see if two active objects (not the same object, mind you) occupy the same position in the reference frame. If they do, this would simulate a collision, the two objects involved would be destroyed, and their instances would be removed from the active objects dictionary.

```
dict actives{ 'missile' : object_c(x1, y1, z1),
              'target'  : object_c(x2, y2, z2),
              'clutter' : object_c(x3, y3, z3),
              ...                               }

...

for key1 in self.actives.keys():
   for key2 in self.actives.keys():
      if not key1 == key2:
         # Get Inertial Positions and Distance
         Pos21 = self.actives[key2].Pos - self.actives[key1].Pos
         distance = math.sqrt(sum(Pos21**2))
         # If Distance <= Critical Distance
         if distance <= 1.0e0
            # Remove key1 and key2 from Actives
            # -- This is where I need help --
```

I can't use `del`:  the keys (and objects) would be removed from actives, but the `for` loops' conditions fail to recognize this and will encounter a KeyError. What can I do to remove these objects from actives while accessing the keys for the loop conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Maximilian Peters had the right basic idea, but the items to be removed should be kept in a `set` rather than a `list` to avoid issues with an active key being in it multiple times. To further hasten the collision detection process, I changed the comparison loop to use the [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) generator function so as to only test unique pairs of objects.

I also had to add a fair amount of scaffolding to make it possible test the code in a context like you probably have it running in...

```
from itertools import combinations
import math

CRITICAL_DIST = 2.0e0

class ObjectC(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.posn = x, y, z
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({}, {}, {})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, *self.posn)

class Game(object):
    def remove_collisons(self):
        to_remove = set()
        for key1, key2 in combinations(self.actives, 2):
             # Calculate distance.
             deltas = (
                 (self.actives[key2].posn[0] - self.actives[key1].posn[0])**2,
                 (self.actives[key2].posn[1] - self.actives[key1].posn[1])**2,
                 (self.actives[key2].posn[2] - self.actives[key1].posn[2])**2)
             distance = math.sqrt(sum(deltas))
             # Check for collision.
             if distance <= CRITICAL_DIST:
                to_remove |= {key1, key2}  # both objects should be removed

        if to_remove:
            print('removing: {!r}'.format(list(to_remove)))
            self.actives = {
                k: v for k, v in self.actives.items() if k not in to_remove}

x1, y1, z1 = 0, 1, 2
x2, y2, z2 = 1, 2, 3
x3, y3, z3 = 2, 3, 1

actives = {'missile' : ObjectC(x1, y1, z1),
           'target'  : ObjectC(x2, y2, z2),
           'clutter' : ObjectC(x3, y3, z3),
          } # ...

game = Game()
game.actives = actives
print('before: {}'.format(game.actives))
game.remove_collisons()
print('after: {}'.format(game.actives))
```

Output:

```
 before: {'clutter': ObjectC(2, 3, 1), 'target': ObjectC(1, 2, 3), 'missile': ObjectC(0, 1, 2)}
 removing: ['target', 'missile']
 after: {'clutter': ObjectC(2, 3, 1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, add the keys you want to remove to a list and then remove them after looping through all elements:

```
dict actives{ 'missile' : object_c(x1, y1, z1),
          'target'  : object_c(x2, y2, z2),
          'clutter' : object_c(x3, y3, z3),
          ...                               }
to_be_removed = list()
```

...

```
for key1 in self.actives.keys():
   for key2 in self.actives.keys():
      if not key1 == key2:
         # Get Inertial Positions and Distance
         Pos21 = self.actives[key2].Pos - self.actives[key1].Pos
         distance = math.sqrt(sum(Pos21**2))
         # If Distance <= Critical Distance
         if distance <= 1.0e0
            # Remove key1 and key2 from Actives
            # -- This is where I need help --


            to_be_removed.append(key1)
            to_be_removed.append(key2)

for remove_me in to_be_removed:
    self.actives.pop(remove_me, None)
```

Comment: That seems almost right, but under the right conditions, the list `to_be_removed` could have multiple instances of `key1` if it occupies the same location as two other objects (i.e. the distance between key1 and key2 is 0.5 and the distance between key1 and key3 is 0.75). Having copies of the same key in the list would also cause a KeyError on `pop`. However, maybe we could record the `to_be_removed` list and clean it up (eliminating duplicated keys) before popping from the dictionary.

Comment: @S.Gamgee: If you specify the `default` value (`None` in this case), there won't be an error if you remove the key from the list.
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 1):

As you're looping, you can double-check that the key is still present:

```
for key1 in self.actives.keys():

    if key1 not in self.actives:
        continue

    for key2 in self.actives.keys():

        if key2 not in self.actives:
            continue

        # okay, both keys are still here.  go do stuff
        if not key1 == key2:
```